# Using replace or regex in database queries

Tags: c#, regex, performance, linq

I'm reading C# 5 in a nutshell, So I came up with a question:
Assume that we have a table in database that has several rows, each row is a string field, Now I want to remove all vowels from the fields. So we can write it this way:

```
var query = names
    .Select (n => n.Replace ("a", "").Replace ("e", "").Replace ("i", "")
            .Replace ("o", "").Replace ("u", ""))
    .Where (n => n.Length > 2)
    .OrderBy (n => n);
```

As you can see `.Replace` method calls five times, So we can easily use regex instead of string’s replace:

```
n => Regex.Replace (n, "[aeiou]", "")
```

The book suggested that in database queries it's better to use string’s Replace  instead of regex's Replace.
My question is that How does it deferentiate? Which one is more efficiency?

Comment: It does not really matter. If there are "several rows" - it will be fast anyway, if there are millons of rows, then it's `Where (n => n.Length > 2)` and `OrderBy (n => n)` that you should address your concerns on.

Comment: If this is LINQ-To-SQL, then some sql providers do not understand RegEx, whereas nearly all of them have some kind of string replacement function.  A RegEx replace may not be convertible to SQL.

Comment: @zerkms: If it's Linq-To-Sql it most certainly is converted to the provider's idea of what SQL is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why** book says avoid RegEx

is because **RegEx are slower** than other built-in comparisons functions.

and think that what would be the time complexity when you're processing several thousands records with RegEx.

and also the time complexity with built-in comparisons functions.

Comment: "RegEx are slower than other built-in comparisons functions" --- this is a terrible statement, especially when you compare 1 regex call with 5 search-replace functions calls.

Comment: "and think that what would be the time complexity when you're processing several thousands records with RegEx." -- think of invoking x5 string processing functions instead.

Comment: zerkms, well said. I got your point. you should edit and improve my answer.